# R colnames/rownames error when creating table by hand

Tags: r

I am trying to directly create a simple 2 column table from data directly in Rstudio.

So the output should be.

```
Material    Kilograms
Iron        5.54
Copper      2.12
Tin         0.27
Zinc        0.60
Nickel      0.23
Barium      0.05
Other       6.44
```

So following the example here [Creating tables directly](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/tables.html#id2) this is the general syntax I should follow.

```
> smoke <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
> colnames(o) <- c("High","Low","Middle")
> rownames(o) <- c("current","former","never")
> smoke <- as.table(smoke)
> smoke
        High Low Middle
current   51  43     22
former    92  28     21
never     68  22      9
```

So adapting my code this is what i have  created  noting that I intend for the first column to have a name of materials.

```
levels <- matrix(c(5.54,2.12,0.27,0.60,0.23,0.05,6.44),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(0) <- c("Materials","Kilograms")
rownames(0) <- c("Iron","Copper","Tin","Zinc","Nickel","Barium","Other")
levels <- as.table(levels)
levels
```

However it  resolves to this.

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
> levels <- matrix(c(5.54,2.12,0.27,0.60,0.23,0.05,6.44),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
> colnames(o) <- c("Materials","Kilograms")
Error in colnames(o) <- c("Materials", "Kilograms") : 
  object 'o' not found
> rownames(o) <- c("Iron","Copper","Tin","Zinc","Nickel","Barium","Other")
Error in rownames(o) <- c("Iron", "Copper", "Tin", "Zinc", "Nickel", "Barium",  : 
  object 'o' not found
> levels <- as.table(levels)
> levels
     A
A 5.54
B 2.12
C 0.27
D 0.60
E 0.23
F 0.05
G 6.44
```

So I assumed that the font may have led me to type **o**  instead of  **0** in the  colnames and rownames  but that still  resulted  in a similar error.

Edit

As there is no answer that can directly create the simple Material Kilograms table posted above should I assume that it is more common or easier to create the tables in excel and link to that or export from excel as csv?

Comment: I couldn't find where you created `o` object.  Perhaps a typo in the link

Comment: What is `o`? it is not defined anywhere? Did you try reading the error messages? I don't get this tutorial at all. In order to reach your desired output replace `o` with `smoke` and skip the `smoke <- as.table(smoke)` all together, as in `smoke <- matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE);
colnames(smoke) <- c("High","Low","Middle");
rownames(smoke) <- c("current","former","never");
smoke`

Comment: In the  example it is not defined, I initially  thought  it was mistyped, since have  tried variations and have  tried leaving it blank and received a NULL error as well.

Comment: Or you could skip this nonsense tutorial all together with just one liner `matrix(c(51,43,22,92,28,21,68,22,9), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("current", "former", "never"), c("High", "Low", "Middle")))`

Comment: Following the  one liner isn't working  for me either . levels <- matrix(c(5.54,2.12,0.27,0.60,0.23,0.05,6.44),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE, dimnames = 
                 list(c("Materials","Kilograms"),c("Iron","Copper","Tin","Zinc","Nickel","Barium","Other")))

Comment: You messes it up. You are trying to set 8*2 dimensions on a 7*1 dimensions matrix. In other words, you've set a one column over 7 rows matrix and trying to give it 2 column names and 8 row names (which doesn't make any sense to R). While my one liner certainly works with the provided data in the original question.

Comment: This question is off topic because the problem was caused by a simple typographical error

Comment: @RichardScriven Happy for you to post an answer I had to not because of typographical error(which didn't cause me an error) but no answer could actually create the table correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is for numbers. data.frame is the standard structure for storing a mixture of data types (and data in general).

You can use the following:

```
o <- data.frame(Material=c("Iron","Copper","Tin","Zinc","Nickel","Barium","Other"), Kilograms=c(5.54,2.12,0.27,0.60,0.23,0.05,6.44), row.names=c("Iron","Copper","Tin","Zinc","Nickel","Barium","Other"))
```

Where the material is both the rowname and a data column in itself.

You could convert a data.frame to a table using

```
xtabs(Kilograms~Material, data=o)
```

but the result will have the levels of Material sorted alphabetically.

Comment: OP doesn't have different classes in his matrix, so no need in `data.frame` in this case

Comment: It seems to create a basic table like this I would actually be quicker writing a csv file and importing it or creating standard tables like this in excel and exporting to csv would you agree?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The data are a text (character/factor) vector and a numeric vector.

Comment: @sayth I think it depends on the situation. Using the data.frame function is very flexible, but with large amounts of data you're better off typing them in in a program like excel or a database. In R, you can edit your objects using the `fix` function if you are working interactively.

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up 0 and o between your last two chunks of code. However, the problem is that you initially write your data to 'levels' but then name the rows and columns of 'o'.

It's generally a bad idea to call variables by the same name as functions, in this case 'levels'.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer I have adapted from [R for Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-data-frame-from-scratch-in-r.html).

The answer appears  to work out very easily and doesn't require complex syntax to achieve, which appeared in the  R tutorials and other SO answers I searched prior.

```
materials <- c("Iron","Copper","Tin","Zinc","Nickel","Barium","Other")
kilograms <- c(5.54,2.12,0.27,0.60,0.23,0.05,6.44)
levels.data <- data.frame(materials,kilograms)
```

If anyone could provide a  better answer or show an improvement that would be appreciated.